# How to access an Array of Objects from one method to other method in JAVA?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

I have created a array of objects that is created from a method here it is named dataInput(). I want to call the persons array in main method. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void dataInput() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int noOfPersons = 3;

    String name = "";
    int no = 0;
    String city = "";

    inputTry[] persons = new inputTry[3];
    persons[0] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
    persons[1] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
    persons[2] = new inputTry(name, no, city);

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfPersons; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter person name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter person number: ");
        no = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter where the person lives: ");
        city = input.nextLine();

        persons[i].name = name;
        persons[i].no = no;
        persons[i].city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make `dataInput` return the array, so you can access it in the calling method.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character and Class names with upper case character.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static inputTry[] dataInput() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int noOfPersons = 3;

    String name = "";
    int no = 0;
    String city = "";

    inputTry[] persons = new inputTry[3];
    persons[0] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
    persons[1] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
    persons[2] = new inputTry(name, no, city);

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfPersons; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter person name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter person number: ");
        no = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter where the person lives: ");
        city = input.nextLine();

        persons[i].name = name;
        persons[i].no = no;
        persons[i].city = city;
    }
    return persons;
}
```

Now in your main method, `inputTry[] persons=datainput()` will fetch the array returned by your method.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    inputTry[] persons = dataInput();
}

public static inputTry[] dataInput() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int noOfPersons = 3;

    String name = "";
    int no = 0;
    String city = "";

    inputTry[] persons = new inputTry[3];
    persons[0] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
    persons[1] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
    persons[2] = new inputTry(name, no, city);

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfPersons; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter person name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter person number: ");
        no = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter where the person lives: ");
        city = input.nextLine();

        persons[i].name = name;
        persons[i].no = no;
        persons[i].city = city;
    }

    return persons;
}
```

You should do something like this, so you can use the return value in the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

- If `dataInput()` is in the same class of **main** 
  You can declare this array global 'in the beginning of the class'.
- If `dataInput()` isn't in the class of **main** 
  You can create a public method called for example, `getPersonsArray()`  and call it from `dataInput()`. Now you can take object from this class and call the method `getPersonsArray()`.

```java
  public static void dataInput() {
     // your code
     inputTry[] persons = new inputTry[3];
     getPersonsArray(name, no, city);
    // your code
  }

    public static inputTry[] getPersonsArray(String name,int no,String city) {
       persons[0] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
       persons[1] = new inputTry(name, no, city);
       persons[2] = new inputTry(name, no, city);

       return persons;
    }
```